# Application context being loaded twice - Spring Boot

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a fairly simple setup. A maven project with 3 modules : core/webapp/model. I'm using Spring boot to gear up my application. In webapp, i have a simple class WebappConfig as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(Configuration.class))
public class WebappConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(WebappConfig.class);
        app.setAdditionalProfiles("dev");
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

and few classes in core/model module. My container-application point is :

```
public class AbcdXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebappConfig.class);
    }

}
```

And no web.xml! My model's pom has following spring boot related dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Core's pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now running WebappConfig via Run as -> Java application works perfectly but i need to deploy the project as a war on tomcat7. Webapp's packaging is war. There is no tomcat provided jar's in lib except tomcat-jdbc and tomcat-tuli jar(Shouldn't be an issue?).

When i deploy my abcd.war, applicationcontext is getting loaded twice and result in following error stracktrace :

```
2014-06-27 11:06:08.445  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/abcd]        : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-06-27 11:06:08.446  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 19046 ms
2014-06-27 11:06:21.308  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2014-06-27 11:06:21.313  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2014-06-27 11:06:21.314  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2014-06-27 11:06:26.073  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2014-06-27 11:06:26.127  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2014-06-27 11:06:26.511  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
2014-06-27 11:06:26.521  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2014-06-27 11:06:26.527  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
//some info messages from spring boot
2014-06-27 11:07:31.664  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-06-27 11:07:33.095  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-06-27 11:07:33.096  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-06-27 11:07:36.080  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2014-06-27 11:08:49.583  INFO 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 183.152 seconds (JVM running for 210.258)
2014-06-27 11:12:29.229 ERROR 23467 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/abcd]        : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:277)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

There is no web.xml as i mentioned earlier.

Few interesting things that i can't figure out why :

1. After exploding the war, tomcat somehow create a ROOT folder with default web.xml[Must be Spring boot misconfiguration. How can i correct it? Pointers please?]
2. Even if i return same 'application' SpringApplicationBuilder in AbcdXml.java, i am facing the same issue of applicationcontext being loaded twice.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT 1:

Content of web.xml that is generated in ROOT folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
</web-app>
```

Comment: What does the mysterious web.xml contain?

Comment: the one that is generated in ROOT folder? updated in the question.

Comment: That looks harmless. But you have a `ContextLoaderListener` in the stack trace which seems wrong. Maybe you could start with a single war file (ditch the other two) and reproduce the problem, then post a link to the whole project?

Comment: Well, model packaging is jar, core's is jar and dependency between modules is usual. Core needs module and webapp needs core. Maybe i am missing something here when you said "Ditch the other two"? There is one war anyway!

Comment: Just trying to reduce the surface area. Maybe one of your jars has a `WebApplicationInitilaizer` in it?

Comment: Yeah, but i couldn't find any offending class. Here is the list of jars in lib folder - http://oi62.tinypic.com/of62yx.jpg just in case if it's useful.

Comment: jersey-spring3 is probably the culprit. There are some utilities for working with jersey here: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-jersey. One of the things it does is prevent Jersey from trying to create a Spring context.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Would have never guessed it. Thanks @DaveSyer :) I can accept/upvote your solution if you post above as an answer else i'll post it anyway so that it might help others.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your app includes jersey-spring3 and you don't take steps to disable, it will try to create an `ApplicationContext` for you (helpful, not). There is a way to switch it off (in a `WebApplicationInitializer`):

```
servletContext.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "<NONE>");
```

Or just use this: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-jersey (include as a dependency).

Answer (score 6):

In my case - I was having the same problem - seeing the Spring `splash screen` twice - It was because I had 2 classes that extended `SpringBootServletInitializer`. One was called `SpringBootWebApplication` and the other `ServletInitializer`. I just removed the `ServletInitializer` and it worked OK. Don't know why there were 2 classes - maybe because I got inspired from 2 different examples to assemble what I needed.

Comment: this exactly was my problem too.

Comment: `ServletInitializer.java` is automatically generated by Spring Boot Starters (when creating a new project in STS for example). This got me too, it's supposed to be a helpful feature :/

Answer (score 1):

In my case the culprit was using Spring Boot 1.3.0.M4, along with Jersey 2.21. When I downgraded Spring Boot to 1.2.6.RELEASE the issue is gone.
The only thing I had to do was to explicitly override the following properties, as I needed spring 4.2.0 for Hibernate 5 support, and jackson 2.6.2 for JSR310 (java8 java.time) support:

```
<spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
<jackson.version>2.6.2</jackson.version>
```

EDIT: As of spring-boot 1.3.0.RELEASE, this bug still exists. See [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4527)

Answer (score 0):

My main problem was my spring context was being loaded twice. As I printed every class's class loader I found that my Application was running twice. (i.e. when I debug in intellij after pressing F9 I was again landing up on same line i.e.

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(ConfigAssignServer.class, args);
```

My problem was in pom.xml. I removed below dependency from my pom and it worked.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please check for your dependencies. Hope it will help someone. Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

I have src>main>webapp>WEB-INF>web.xml has an entity to saying

```html
<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This is loading my context second time.

Comment it out and it will load only once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.5 and experiencing the same issue but without error (WebApplicationContext) is being loaded twice along with scheduler calls are triggered as well too.

After debugging my application & Server(Tomcat v9.0.53) settings, I, myself able to solve the issue by deleting the "ServletInitializer.java" class which comes part of Spring initialiser project.

Now, all the issues resolved like schedulers are called once on predefined time along with the context loading.

Hope this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `"extends SpringBootServletInitializer"` not work well with `@SpringBootApplication` in tomcat but when run with maven no duplicated beans is initialized so removing `"extends SpringBootServletInitializer"` from application main class solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In the Spring framework, usually for loading something like a `global` or `root` context, you club all the `bean/resources` shared by multiple servlet contexts.
Or loading a specific servlet context. `Mvc-dispatcher` config file is used to load config file, so you don't need to explicitly define it.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In your case, seems when you are running as a Java application, auto-detection of Mvc-dispatcher doesn't happen and you are able to execute the code successfully. Whereas when deployed it gets initiated both from root and mvc-dispatcher.

Use empty context: `<context-param/>`

I don’t see the contents of `web.xml` here, So I am throwing a quick suggestion from both perspectives.

- Please try to delete dependency from the `global/root` context.
- Or in case `@EnableAutoConfiuguration` is used, get rid of it.

Answer (score -2):

[@EnableAutoConfiuguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/0.5.0.M3/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html) from the API says "Enable auto-configuration of the Spring Application Context, attempting to guess and configure beans that you are likely to need."

[@ComponentScan](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) would also instantiate the beans. IT will scan the packages, find and register the beans.

As you are using both these annotations, I guess that is why its loading twice.

Comment: I don't think so! They are in both different context. Well, it didn't work anyway.