# Spring boot RESTful service as WAR not JAR

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I am in the process of creating a Java REST application, using Spring-boot. I have successfully loaded the [example here](http://jasenkoh.blogspot.ro/2014/11/java-restful-web-services-with-spring.html) and I have tried to convert the JAR file to the WAR file as presented on the Spring-boot site. I've modified my pom.xml file, adding:

```xml
<!-- other pom.xml conf -->
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then I've modified the Application.java class to initialize the servlet (this is for what Spring-boot uses to replace the web.xml file):

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
//    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).run(args);
//    }

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/*");
      registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyInitialization.class.getName());
    return registration;
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

}
```

I got my .WAR file generated, but when I deploy it on Tomcat the services are returning 404. The Tomcat logs aren't showing any errors either.

So I am not sure what it might be the problem. If you have any idea please, do share. Thanks!

---

### Update:

Initially it wasn't working because beside the SpringBootApplication annotation to the Application class I was having other annotations too. Took those out and now Tomcat logs are showing this error.

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!

I am not sure what other ContextLoader is there.

---

### UpdateToUpdate:

Okay, after updating the jars to the latest version, using the annotation @SpringBootApplication for Application.java class, the application starts but when I am calling one of the services I receive:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestExecutorFactory

A google search said that I should add the jersey-common and jersey-core jars, I did, but it didn't fix it. It looks like the RequestExecutorFactory.class is not packaged in the jersey-common-2.19.jar for some reason.

Comment: Did you annotate class `Application` with `@SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: Yes, I did annotate the Application class with '@SpringBootApplication', and that created: public @interface SpringBootApplication {} (I am not sure if that is right though.)

Comment: This annotation comes from spring boot, you cannot create your own. Publish your project on github - there is something wrong outside of the files you pasted here

Comment: Okay, here it is the github project https://github.com/elf11/Spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-jersey-hibernate (I deleted the created interface for SpringBootApplication)

Comment: First of all - do you really need Jersey for REST endpoints? If you do, take a look first at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey - in your code I have a feeling that you're making things overcomplex (dependencies in pom).

Comment: It's an exercise, I want first to make it work as it is right now, and then change it and try different things. The complexity of the pom.xml file doesn't explain though why the SpringBootApplication annotation is not found I think ... :( I did add the two jars to the project, in the dependencies and in the pom.xml (spring-boot-starter-jersey and spring-boot-starter-actuator) but the SpringBootApplication annotation is still not found.

Comment: SpringBootApplication is not found because you use old spring boot version. Anyway it's just a shorthand for 3 annotations that you already have on Application class

Comment: The problem seems to be with the ServletRegistrationBean and the SpringApplicationBuilder, one duplicates the other. Is there any way to make them work together?

Answer (score 1):

why do you have so many annotation in your `Application` class [here](https://github.com/elf11/Spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-jersey-hibernate/src/main/java/com/jersey/Application.java) ?

`@SpringBootApplication` should be sufficient to enable automatic configuration.
Try removing the others.

And put back the main method.

I think you mixed two configuration tw create a war : pre 3.0 and post 3.0 servlet container (as per the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file))

EDIT :

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445041/application-context-being-loaded-twice-spring-boot) related to your problem.

Jersey is loading a Spring ApplicationContext. See this line of log : `Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.jersey.Application@148ac084, org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer@7807c6d3]`

Would it be possible for you to update your Spring Boot version ?
At least 1.20 so you will be able to use the `spring-boot-starter-jersey`. It will be a lot more easier to integrate Spring and Jersey.

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey) (Spring Boot official examples).

Or you have to exclude the `org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer` of initializers

Comment: The SpringBootApplication annotation is not working, I am using version 1.1.9 of Springboot and that annotation is not present, so the other 3 annotations should be equivalent. Other than that, I added back the main method as per that link, but if I deploy the war on an external Tomcat I get no error in the logs. I've tried running the war with: java -jar  myApp.war and I get _org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class_ . It doesn't find the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class

Comment: I will check your project on github and see if I can solve the problem. If that's the case, I will create a pull request.

Comment: Also I've just created a [pull request](https://github.com/elf11/Spring-boot/pull/1/files) with new configuration and version to integrate Spring Boot and Jersey

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help, but your pull-request brings me exactly where I was with my project, I get this error: _java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/process/internal/RequestExecutorFactory [..] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestExecutorFactory_